# "convergence" of unbounded operators on Fock space

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, unbounded-operators

For the Hilbert space of a single mode in quantum optics (i.e. the Fock space), I'd like to be able to capture the intuition that eigenstates of the operators $a_g=ga+\sqrt{g^2-1}a^\dagger$ look more and more like position eigenstates (with eigenvalue going to zero) as $g\rightarrow\infty$.

Defining a sequence $T_n=g^{-1}\left(ga+\sqrt{g^2-1}a^\dagger\right)$, I'd like to say that it converges in some sense to $T=a+a^\dagger$. Obviously since $T_n-T$ is unbounded, looking at norms won't be useful. But for coherent states $\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle$, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\|(T_n-T)\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle\|&=\|[g^{-1}\left(ga+\sqrt{g^2-1}a^\dagger\right)-(a+a^\dagger)]\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle\|
\\
&=\left(\sqrt{1-1/g^2}-1\right)\|a^\dagger\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle\|
\\
&=\left(\sqrt{1-1/g^2}-1\right)\sqrt{\left\langle\alpha\right\vert aa^\dagger\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle}
\\
&=\left(\sqrt{1-1/g^2}-1\right)\sqrt{\left\vert\alpha\right\vert^2+1}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{g\rightarrow\infty}\|(T_n-T)\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle\|=0\hspace{10pt}\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{C}.
\end{equation}
This looks sort of like strong operator convergence, since the coherent states are a basis for the Fock space and the argument works for $\textit{finite}$ linear combinations of coherent states, but of course there are vectors in the Fock space that are not in the domain of $T_n-T$, which is already only defined on the intersection of the domains of $T_n$ and $T$.

I'm guessing that these issues are why I can't find much about "convergence" of sequences of unbounded operators, but is there something that captures this idea?

Comment: What do the the operators $a_g=ga+\sqrt{g^2-1}a^\dagger$ represent physically (so we have an "intuition")? What does "coherent state" mean mathematically? I know a bit about QFT and operator theory, but you are not speaking my language.

Comment: The operators $a_g$ can be thought of as the creation operator in the Heisenberg picture after the application of some "amplifier", i.e. a unitary map. The coherent state $\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle$ is the eigenstate of the annihilation operator $a$ with eigenstate $\alpha$. Physically, they're minimum uncertainty states for position and momentum, and they have the property that $\left\langle x(t)\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle p(t)\right\rangle$ follow the phase-space trajectory of a classical harmonic oscillator.

Comment: If you were to plot the Wigner quasiprobability distribution of the $\alpha_g$-eigenstate for increasing $g$ (equivalently the distribution for the coherent state $U_g\left\vert\alpha\right\rangle$ where $a_g=U^\dagger aU$) you'd see it get stretched along the $p$ direction and squeezed along the $x$ direction.

Comment: Maybe a cleaner way to state that is that if you look at the marginal distributions on $x$ by integrating the Wigner functions over $p$, they'd be Gaussians that got narrower with increasing $g$. I know that such a sequence doesn't converge in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but it seems like there ought to be some way to capture the idea that they look more like eigenfunctions of the multiplication operator $x$ as the get narrower.